# Firebase database how to prevent concurrent reads?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

**Use case:**

User will get a password for a door (e.g. `door2`, password `222`) when they are at a particular location (e.g. `LocationA`). After that the cloud function will remove the door from the `empty` documents and add it to the `occupied` document.

**Initial database:**

```
"LocationA" : {
  "empty" : {
    "door2" : {
      "password" : "222"
    },
    "door3" : {
      "password" : "333"
    }
  },
  "occupied" : {
    "door1" : {
      "password" : "111"
    }
  }
}
```

**After user get a password for a empty door:**

```
"LocationA" : {
  "empty" : {
    "door3" : {
      "password" : "333"
    }
  },
  "occupied" : {
    "door1" : {
      "password" : "111"
    },
    "door2" : {
      "password" : "222"
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

What if there are 2 users concurrently gets the `door2` password? Will this scenario occur?

I would like to have user 1 to get `door2` and user 2 to get `door3` respectively.

This is the code I'm using to get the door:

```
// Read Lockers QR User(CRUD)
exports.getQRCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.database().ref('lockers/' + 'LocationA/' + 'empty').limitToFirst(1).once("value",snap=> {
        console.log('QR Code for door:',snap.val());
        var qrCodesForDoor = snap.val();
        res.send(qrCodesForDoor); 
    });
});
```

**Updated base on Grimthorr answer**

```
exports.getQRCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {


admin.database().ref('lockers/LocationA/empty').limitToFirst(1).once("value", snap=> {
  // Get the name of the first available door and use a transaction to ensure it is not occupied
  console.log('QR Code for door:',snap.val());
  var door = Object.keys(snap.val())[0];
  console.log('door:',door);

  // var door = snap.key();
  var occupiedRef = admin.database().ref('lockers/LocationA/occupied/'+door);
  occupiedRef.transaction(currentData=> {
      if (currentData === null) {
          console.log("Door does not already exist under /occupied, so we can use this one.");
          return snap.child(door).val(); // Save the chosen door to /occupied
      } else {
          console.log('The door already exists under /occupied.');
          return nil; // Abort the transaction by returning nothing
      }
  }, (error, committed, snapshot) => {
      console.log('snap.val():',snap.val());
      if (error) {
          console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
          res.send("Unknown error."); // This handles any abormal error
      } else if (!committed) {
          console.log('We aborted the transaction (because the door is already occupied).');
          res.redirect(req.originalUrl); // Refresh the page so that the request is retried
      } else {
          // The door is not occupied, so can be given to this user
          admin.database().ref('lockers/LocationA/empty/'+door).remove(); // Delete the door from /empty
          console.log('QR Code for door:',snapshot.val());
          var qrCodesForDoor = snapshot.val();
          res.send(qrCodesForDoor); // Send the chosen door as the response
      }
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds similar to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition):

> the behavior of [...] software where the output is dependent on the sequence or timing of other uncontrollable events. It becomes a bug when events do not happen in the order the programmer intended.

This seems like an unlikely scenario when using a realtime database, especially when used in a Cloud Function, but it's not entirely impossible.

The Firebase SDK provides [transaction operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) which can be used to avoid concurrent modifications. For your scenario, using the Admin SDK in Node.js, you could perform something like the following:

```javascript
// Read Lockers QR User(CRUD)
exports.getQRCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.database().ref('lockers/LocationA/empty').limitToFirst(1).once("value", (snap) => {
        if (!snap.hasChildren()) {
            res.send("No doors available.");
            return;
        }
        // Get the name of the first available door and use a transaction to ensure it is not occupied
        var door = Object.keys(snap.val())[0]; // The limitToFirst always returns a list (even with 1 result), so this will select the first result
        var occupiedRef = admin.database().ref('lockers/LocationA/occupied/'+door);
        occupiedRef.transaction((currentData) => {
            if (currentData === null) {
                console.log("Door does not already exist under /occupied, so we can use this one.");
                return snap.val(); // Save the chosen door to /occupied
            } else {
                console.log('The door already exists under /occupied.');
                return; // Abort the transaction by returning nothing
            }
        }, (error, committed, snapshot) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
                res.send("Unknown error."); // This handles any abormal error
            } else if (!committed) {
                console.log('We aborted the transaction (because the door is already occupied).');
                res.redirect(req.originalUrl); // Refresh the page so that the request is retried
            } else {
                // The door is not occupied, so can be given to this user
                admin.database().ref('lockers/LocationA/empty/'+door).remove(); // Delete the door from /empty
                console.log('QR Code for door:',snapshot.val());
                var qrCodesForDoor = snapshot.val();
                res.send(qrCodesForDoor); // Send the chosen door as the response
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This uses your existing code to obtain the next available door, with the difference being that it will only select this door if it doesn't yet exist under the `/occupied` node. It achieves this by making use of a transaction to check the value of the `/occupied/door#` node before choosing it, and applies the below logic:

- If the door **does not exist** under `/occupied`, we can safely select this door, save it to `/occupied` and delete it from `/empty`.
- If the door **does exist** under `/occupied`, then someone else has beaten us to it, so the request page is refreshed to trigger the function again, thus (hopefully) selecting a different door next time.

Comment: Can I buy you a beer? xD

Comment: Just one more issue... I'm not familiar with transaction. With the above code it will save a new object in the occupied documents however, it has an additonal key         "door4" : {
          "door4" : {
            "password" : "444"
          }
        } How to remove the door4 key?

Comment: @user1872384 I wish! This was an interesting question & challenge for me, thanks for the question!

Comment: @user1872384 Ah, that's because `limitToFirst` always returns a list of children (even with just 1 item), so line 10 will need to select the only child instead. See my edit, which should achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Grimthorr, got it to work base on the modification. Added a few minor tweak as well